# Using external drive as a primary storage for iCloud

Tags: icloud

I'm going to buy an external high-performance 2TB SSD and want to use it as a primary local storage for iCloud, instead of a standard internal SSD 256GB of my MacBook Pro.

The question is – how to switch iCloud from using standard internal SSD to external?

Is there some terminal command, that allows to "redirect" iCloud sync process to another location?